# In a WPF Program, I want to change the Stroke Color on all the "Lines" on a "Canvas"

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have a bunch of lines on a canvas.
I want to iterate through the Lines and turn their Stroke colors to black.

The line of code in the foreach loop won't compile.

```
foreach (FrameworkElement Framework_Element in My_Canvas.Children)
{
    //the following line of code won't compile.
    (Line)Framework_Element.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
```

Comment: What is the underlying type of `Stroke` and what type is `SolidColorBrush` and its parent? Look into this, and you should get some clues as to how to answer the question yourself.

Comment: @ChrisBallard I  guess I ruined your teaching moment.  :>

Comment: In a typical WPF application you would not do this. Instead, you might define a SolidColorBrush resource and set all the Line's Strokes to that resource. Later, you would only change the Color of the SolidColorBrush resource. Or, you would bind the Stroke property to a Brush property in the application's view model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a pair of parenthesis.

```
foreach (FrameworkElement Framework_Element in My_Canvas.Children)
  {
    // tries to find .Stroke on the FrameworkElement class
    // (Line)Framework_Element.Stroke

    // correct way
    ((Line)Framework_Element).Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

    // or

    var currentLine = (Line)Framework_Element;
    currentLine.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
  }
```

Comment: I'm always getting screwed up on these parenthesis. The code now works fine with                                               ((Line)Framework_Element).Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);